# buildout configuration issue for my django project,not get specified version of django

Tags: python, django, buildout

I installed `zc.buildout` using `easy_install`. I used the tutorial  at http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/.

My problem is,
am not able to install the versions specified in the buildout.cfg:

```ini
[buildout]
parts = python 
        django
develop = .
versions = versions

eggs = nltk
       html5lib
       pysolr
       python-openid
       django-shorturls

[versions]
django = 1.4.1

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
```

When I try ./bin/python

```
>>> import pysolr
>>> pysolr           #  it worked from my buildout 
<module 'pysolr' from '/home/builout-tests/sandbox/eggs/pysolr-3.0.4-py2.7.egg/pysolr.pyc'>
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)  # its my django version in system's python dist-packages
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

And also how can I keep different versions of python, django, pylsolr, nltk, etc. for development and production versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing django by Django (with a caps D) in your [versions] section

Comment: when I try /bin/buildout after ,the change you suggested,it show Getting distribution for 'Django==1.2.5'.  ................  Got Django 1.2.5. But stil when I print django ,its show the systems django version

Comment: 1.2.5 ? You have 1.4.1 in your buildout.cfg. Anyway you seems to have an other problem as it shows the system version and not the one you just installed. Strange.

Comment: sorry I changed django version in buildout to 1.2.5 ,

Answer (score 0):

The eggs you specify in your `[buildout]` part don't really do anything. It is common practice to put eggs there that you need in a couple of parts, like `[python]` and `[django]` in your case.

So... fix number one is to add `eggs = ${buildout:eggs}` to your `[django]` part, as that's probably what you intend.

Regarding the django/Django upper/lowercase version: there are two solutions for it. If you use a pre-2.0 buildout version, add `extension = buildout-versions` to your `[buildout]` part. It prints versions it picked and it removes the case sensitiveness.

Best option, though, is to use the latest 2.0 buildout. You probably have to download a fresh `bootstrap.py` from http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py and re-run bootstrap and `bin/buildout`. This also removes case insensitiveness. For more clarity, add `show-picked-versions = true` to your `[buildout]` part to get a nice listing of picked versions. Way easier to spot weirdness and unexpected behaviour that way :-)

Comment: I download latest bootstrap and run pythonbootstrap.py and ./bin/buildout.    Still have isssue